Unpacking RAR archive, but one of the parts (segments) in UPPER CASE filename and extension, any ideas about workaround for this?
For some reason, example.mpg turned into several RARs, part01.rar part02.rar etc, all the way to part22.rar, but ONE of the RARs, is this PART07.RAR (in capital letters), so the WinRar or 7-zip cannot unpack that segment because it's in upper case?  I've tried renaming part7 so it looks like part7.RAR but it still won't like it LOL.  Any ideas?  Would any of the related PAR files be able to "reconstitute" the missing correctly-named RAR?

Are you ABSOLUTELY POSITIVELY IMPOSSIBLE TO QUESTION certain that part07 is actually from the same multivolume archive?

Sounds like your archive is incomplete. Without that last part the file cannot be extracted

Yes, I had a scan of it with QuickPar, using the repair Par to indicate if the capitalized part07.rar was missing any blocks, and it said yes, so looks like the part07.rar in capitals, was not all there anyway.
